# Show message only in safari browser

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I want to display a message on a website homepage only on Safari browser but not on other browsers because website having few issues in Safari so I would like to navigate users to use other browsers by showing up alert on website. I would like to know solution for this in vb.net or jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to show like message instead of alert on a banner. could you please tell me that would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

1)When the script runs it will check if browser is safari.

2)If it is, we get the empty div, we set the html and we add the appropriate classes to display an alert.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div role="alert" id='alert-if-safari'></div>

    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>

    <script>
        
        var is_safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        if (is_safari) {
            const alert_div = document.getElementById('alert-if-safari')
            alert_div.className = 'alert alert-danger'
            alert_div.innerHTML = 'Open my website via chrome browser!'
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to show like message instead of alert on a banner. could you please tell me that would be helpful to me

Comment: @Harisha I edit my answer. Is that what you want?